# RecyclerView restore scroll state while setting new LayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-orientation

I'm trying to save and restore states of RecyclerView on orientation in fragment changed and it kinda works, but with 1 layout manager only. For example: if it's LinearLayoutManager only, it maintains position, but once rotating and changing to StaggeredGrid, it loads items but loses scroll position.

```
if (Configuration.landscape(getActivity())) {
        newslistview.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    } else {
        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet)) {
            newslistview.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        } else {
            newslistview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        }
    }
```

This is a code for layout changing on orientation, it's inside onCreateView and after that is instance check:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        productsListSaved = new ArrayList<>();
        productsListSaved = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("newsfeed");
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), productsListSaved);
        newslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        new Synchronize.LoadAllProducts(getActivity()).execute(categorie);
    }
```

Is it even possible to save & restore & change layout manager at the same time?

Comment: Solved. Solution: Use GridLayoutManager for both case

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of such a simple and justifiable solution.